# Use of large Business Objects with fewer properties

Tags: c#

I have a large Business Objects let's say having 50 properties. Now for a method I need only 5-10 properties. So is it good idea to use the same large object in that method or create a new BO with fewer properties.

Comment: ultimately, it's entirely up to you.  Personally I'd consider doing so bad design, as you now have 2 object types resembling effectively the same thing.

Comment: Aside from the actual question, can you break your object down into smaller pieces? 50 properties is quite a lot.. For example, a `Car` object wouldn't need have properties for every single component. You could break the engine components into a separate `Engine` object, which exists in a `Car`. Then you could pass just do something like `TheMethod(yourCar.Engine)` rather than passing an entire `Car` and accessing only Engine-like properties. It's mostly a maintainability/readability thing IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your BO is a class (and not a struct). Then what the method gets is a single reference to this BO, not a copy of all the properties

```
void Method(BO bo)
{
    // Here bo is a reference to the passed business object.
    // No properties have been copied.
}
```

Therefore, it is not a problem to call the method with a large Business Objects having many properties.

---

Another aspect is conceptual. The [Interface segregation principle (ISP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use (and a property is a pair of getter and setter methods). Therefore, you could formulate different aspects of the BO through different interfaces. Let's assume that this method wants to print the address. Only a few properties belong to the address.

```
public class CustomerBO : IAddress
{
    #region IAddress members

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    #endregion

    // ... lots of other properties here
}
```

The method

```
void PrintAddress(IAddress address) 
{
    // This method does not need to know other proeprties.
}
```

The advantage is that other objects could implement `IAddress` like a supplier. This enhances the reusability of the method.

Comment: Or have CustomerBO have an IAddress Adress property

Comment: Yes. From the perspective of the `PrintAddress` method it makes no difference and enhances its reusability even more. Whether you do this also depends on whether you have distinct view models, BOs and DTO's or not and whether you want to store the BO in a single table, etc. It's good to have both options to choose from.